# Can't find span text in selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

enter code hereI am doing web scraping to a movie page but it does not find the span although in the xpath it is fine and it recognizes it, it does not find the text, when I print it, it prints empty.

This is the code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9S8x.png)

Evidence finding the item
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzTYY.png)

Url

https://www.cinecolombia.com/cali/peliculas/el-olvido-que-seremos
xpath

//section[@class="collapsible show-times-collapse"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9S8x.png)//div[@class="show-times-group"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9S8x.png)//div[@class="show-times-group__attrs"]/span[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9S8x.png)

the element at the end is with brackets, I don't recognize it stack span

xpath
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsEEw.png)

And also try what was recommended to me in the answers and it doesn't work either
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqu5B.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this XPath:

```
(//div[@class='show-times-group__attrs']/span)[1]
```

**UPD**
That element is initially hidden inside collapsible element.
So, to see it with Selenium you first have to open it.
The code to get the text will be:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.show-times-collapse__header"))).click()

your_text = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='show-times-group__attrs']/span)[1]"))).text
```

Comment: still does not take the text of the span

Comment: what command do you use? Maybe you are missing a delay before it?

Comment: How am I running it in jupyter in cell 3 opens the browser and leaves it there open so that I can still do tests, with the browser open.

Comment: Can you show me how you do it from the code to get the text from the span?